# Scrpit R with pandas

Tags: r, pandas

I actually used R to remove duplicated sequences such as:

```
seq1      seq2 
seq2      seq1 
seq3      seq4 
seq5      seq6
```

and get

```
seq1      seq2
seq3      seq4 
seq5      seq6
```

by doing:

```
data<-read.table("dataframe.txt")

for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  data[i,c(2,3)] = sort(data[i,c(2,3)])
}

data2 = data[!duplicated(data[,c(2,3)]),]

write.csv(data2,"data_without_duplicated")
```

Does someone know how to do it with pandas?

Here is an example of the real data:

```
cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident_x    pident_y    length  qstart  qend    sstart  send    qspec   sspec
13  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0035_0035_1 EOG090X00GO_0042_0035_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1175    1   1179    0035    0042
14  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0035_0035_1 EOG090X00GO_0042_0042_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1175    1   1179    0035    0042
16  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0035_0042_1 EOG090X00GO_0042_0035_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1175    1   1179    0035    0042
17  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0035_0042_1 EOG090X00GO_0042_0042_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1175    1   1179    0035    0042
19  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0042_0035_1 EOG090X00GO_0035_0035_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1179    1   1175    0042    0035
20  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0042_0035_1 EOG090X00GO_0035_0042_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1179    1   1175    0042    0035
22  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0042_0042_1 EOG090X00GO_0035_0035_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1179    1   1175    0042    0035
23  cluster_016663  EOG090X00GO_0042_0042_1 EOG090X00GO_0035_0042_1 0.93    93.0    1179    1   1179    1   1175    0042    0035
```

Here is my script:

```
data_wo_eqSpec.to_csv("dataframe.txt", sep='\t')
print("prem1:",data_wo_eqSpec.shape)

data_wo_eqSpec=data_wo_eqSpec.astype(str) 
data_wo_eqSpec.iloc[:,1:3]=np.sort(data_wo_eqSpec.iloc[:,1:3].values,1)

data_wo_eqSpec2= data_wo_eqSpec.drop_duplicates(list(data_wo_eqSpec.iloc[:,1:3]))

print("prem:",data_wo_eqSpec2.shape)

data_wo_eqSpec=pd.read_csv("data_without_duplicated")

print("deus:",data_wo_eqSpec.shape)
```

here are the data: [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RkayZK-8ov55m8nULwa0Ee0DV5wncHUR/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Python`

```
data.iloc[:,2:4]=np.sort(data.iloc[:,2:4].values,1)
data2 = data.drop_duplicates(list(data.iloc[:,2:4]))
```

For R without for loop , using `apply`

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[,c(1,2)],1,sort))),]
```

Comment: Hi again, in fact it seem I got an issue trying to use this code : I'm getting:  File "cluster_test.py", line 50, in <module>
    data_wo_eqSpec.iloc[:,1:3]=np.sort(data_wo_eqSpec.iloc[:,2:4].values,1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 847, in sort
    a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @Benjamin it is better show us the data ..or you just do df=df.astype(str)

Comment: @Benjamin `df=df.astype(str)`

Comment: I tried and it runs but I do not get the same result as when I do it with the R script

Comment: @Benjamin I think that is just sort order different

Comment: My firt dataframe have 12876 columns at the beginning and when I run the R script I get the around the half (6631) what is expected but with the python script I get 10421 rows at the end on the process

Comment: @Benjamin base on my understating , this two line are same , really confused now ..

Comment: I made a mistake sorry, but it actually still gives me something differrent (R gives: 6631 and python: 6766). I posted the script I used at the end of the first post, maybe I wrote something wrong?

Comment: @Benjamin this is hard to help you out without see the full data , but I can guess there is some NaN or NA in your data

Comment: I added the data in a link. I made a crt+F and did not find any NaN it is weird